# Call builder.load and then duplicating component

Tags: nativescript

I am currently using the ui/builder to load a component with an xml and js file like this:

```
let component = builder.load({
    path: 'pages/path/to/component',
    name: 'component'
});
```

I then add the component to an existing view.  This all works fine, but I am actually calling this up to hundreds of times because the parent contains many of these components (similar to a repeater containing a lot of items).  Does the builder.load method need to be called every time with the path to the xml/js files, or can the in-memory component be duplicated?  Would there be a performance benefit to doing things this way, or does the nativescript builder already keep a cache of referenced components?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a performance hit as the builder will parse the XML every time to create the JavaScript instance, you may keep a reference to the returned component after first call to builder.

But it could be still a performance hit as you are going to load 100s of components. You must consider using `ListView` that recycles the unused views as needed.

If you use builder / repeater, you are actually creating 100s of elements on screen, when `ListView` is used it creates only elements those are visible on screen. As you scroll down or up, it is going to reuse the elements those are off screen that improves the performance a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Most of the time I won't have hundreds, but it is possible.  I am developing an expandable/collapsible bracket (each component is a game between teams) and using the listview doesn't quite do what I want.  If I store the reference, how do I reuse it (reinitialize) after adding it the first time without reparsing?  I am passing attributes on the load call, so I don't need to reparse the xml, but I do need to execute the onLoad javascript method.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. Actually you can't keep reference when it is an instance that returned from builder. The only way you could avoid parsing XML every time is to write your custom component in JavaScript itself. And in my opinion, parsing XML is not going to take much than loading 100s of elements on screen. If you do lazy loading, may be then you will save the load time.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty quick right now.  I was just looking for a way to optimize if it was something easy (e.g. ref = builder.load ... ref.duplicate).  I'll just stick with calling the load every time for now unless someone has a better idea.  Thanks again!